# How to create vector roads center lines from raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, vectorization

[image: Results]I need to know how to create roads vector center lines from raster using ArcGIS. 
I have tried to use Iso Cluster Unsupervised classification tool to classify raster and set it to 30 classes. After that Reclassify tool to filter the roads cells from other values. After that I have used "Raster to polyline" tool and checked the Simplify box, but the results are a lot of lines looking like a polygons (screenshot). I need it to be just one road center line.
This is a classic topographic map and I have a lot of roads to process so this can`t be a semi-manual process, I need it automatically as much as that is possible.

Does anyone know better way to solve my problem?

Comment: Hi user104851, could you provide more details? Maybe a couple of printscreens of original raster and final product. That way we can try to give a better informed guess. Cheers

Comment: How big is your area?  If not too large or complex, digitizing by hand can often be quicker and more accurate than trying to wrestle vector data out of rasters programatically.

Comment: That is a classic topographic map contains roads, railroads, waterways, cities, etc, The roads that I want to filter and create the center lines of it are red colored. Also that is a very big area.

Comment: Make sure you **edit your question** with any clarifications.  Don't put them in the comments.  Do you have a lot of roads to process or can this be a semi-manual process?  You could create polygons from the road rasters, then convert to line, clip off the ends, and use the tool 'collapse dual lines to centerline'.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: @PolyGeo  I have edited my question.

Comment: You say "the results are not really good" but we cannot see them nor the precise parameter values you used with each tool in your workflow.

Comment: @PolyGeo  Is it better now? I have described all.

Comment: Why no picture? Just save a screenshot and use the Picture button to upload it.

Comment: @PolyGeo Could you please tell me how to add picture?

Comment: @PolyGeo Picture added...

Comment: Do you have the Arcscan extension and have you tried to use it?

Comment: Yes, I have ArcScan extension

Comment: Have you tried ArcScan or is that considered not automatic enough for your purposes?  I think your question needs to say whether you have tried and/or eliminated ArcScan.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved the problem using ArcScan toolbox. Great tool, exactly what I need.